# How to validate array of objects in laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-8, laravel-formrequest

I have an array of objects with different, dynamic parameters. And I'm trying to find a way to validate it based on the object type value.
Is there any way to make it with the FormRequest?

```
[
  {
    type: “link”, 
    url: “https://link.com”, 
    ...
  }, 
  {
    type: “image”, 
    id: “drre-ggre-765”, 
    image: “url”
    ...
  }
]
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-nested-array-input
 Does this helps you ?

Comment: @PSA no, not really. It’s perfectly works when I know the structure of the object. But, in my case I need to choose a validation rules, for each object from the array, based on “type: value.”

Comment: perhaps you could loop over the array and build the validation based on the properties existing within - of course you could define these based on type like so:
`$this->{'validate' . ucwords($object->type)}($object);` which would then call `$this->validateImage($object)` for example.